# Bluetooth Numeric Comparsion pairing for devices without display

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, protocols

According to the [Bluetooth 5.2 manual](https://faculty-web.msoe.edu/johnsontimoj/EE4980/files4980/Core_v5.2.pdf), pages 1641-1642, Table 2.8, Numeric Comparison pairing should be used in cases when both devices have a display. These displays can be used to show confirm Yes/No prompts on both devices as part of authentication. (Figure 2.3, page 1648). However, from the perspective of protocol message exchange sequences for Numeric Comparison, it appears that even if one of the devices does not have display IO the Numeric Comparison pairing can be used. In particular, instead of displaying the passcode on both of the devices, it can be displayed on one of the devices (assume device A) and the other device (assumer device B) merely enters the same passcode through the keypad. The internally generated same passcode (Va=Vb) can be matched with entered passcode on device B and can be confirmed Yes/No prompt on device B. The rest of the procedure can be followed as the standard method (Passkey Entry pairing, page 1652, Figure 2.5).

Is there anything wrong with my understanding here? Is there any security implication of using Numeric Comparison pairing with devices not having displays?

Comment: Yes, it can be done that way but it also known as "just works" pairing (when device simple response yes to any Numeric Comparison request). The Numeric Comparison is less secure than Provide Passkey or Passkey Notification pairing because any can confirm pairing (even you connected to wrong device). Passkey requires to enter passkey that you can see on client (initiator) or on server (receipient). If server has only keyboard you must type a password from client. If server has only display you must type a password on client's keyboard. Less chance to connect to wrong device.

Comment: I am aware of "Just Works" which has no authentication. On the contrary, Numeric Comparison has authentication phases. I don't think "anyone can confirm pairing" for Numeric Comparison because the user will look at his connecting devices to match the digit-code. As a user, I would not press Yes/No for any random connection from unknown device.

Comment: Jsut works uses authentication and it is actually simple Numeric Comparison with automatic accepting. Nothing more. Yes, I agree about not pressing "Yes/No" but in 90% cases autoconfirmation is build-in for numeric comparison for lot of applications.

Answer (score 0):

### DisplayYesNo and NoInputNoOutput devices

Numeric Comparison and Just Works have similar pairing protocols, just that in Just Works some important checks are skipped, which leads to the pairing protocol to produce unauthenticated link keys.

The danger of Just Works and unauthenticated link keys is that they are vulnerable to so called NiNo MitM (NoInputNoOutput Machine-in-the-Middle) attack. This is a practical attack with real-world impact.

What you proposed will result in Just Works, as the second device won't have a screen and a user won't have any ability to visually confirm the numbers. Confirming numbers is an important security step in Bluetooth as it makes active MitM attacks succeed only with a probability of 0.000001

#### DisplayYesNo and DisplayOnly devices

Also I saw that you might have thought of one device showing Yes/No confirmation (user's phone for example), and then the other one just showing a code. With my knowledge of a protocol I cannot say that it should actually result in Just Works, if the second device outputs a code and a user can visually confirm it (I might miss something, except for when the system is programmed to force Just Works and not show the actual code on a second device).

But such a settings makes a second device more vulnerable to unauthorized connections, and might allow or ease other exploitation steps (Implementation specific). That's why if you are a developer I'd urge you to implement the protocol as said in the specification - Both devices executing Numeric Comparison should have a way to confirm or deny the code, both!

Additionally here is a table from the Bluetooth SIG website for your understanding:

[Bluetooth SIG pairing method table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl9Xm.png)